# Password solution for local database, passed between client and server

Tags: c++, security, passwords, sql-server-ce

I have been working on a project that uses an sqlce database that is sent between the client, that needs to work off line, and a server that stores information database, the database is password protected.

The hard part is, we have a business requirement that the users don't have to update to the latest version before reporting the information in the sqlce database and may even be a few generations behind with the latest version of the client and a possible updated password that the server needs to access the reported information in the database.

Our current solution is to have the same static password, in the source code, on the client and the server and keeping them the same for backward compatibility.

**My question is about a secure way to sync the password between the client and the server and keeping backward compatibility for older databases or being able to get some parameter from the database to see what password should match.**

We use sql ce 3.1 and C++ at moment. solutions to the same problem in other technologies (SQLight? C#? Java?) are welcome since I think the problem can be applied on other projects.

I hope my problem is clear and that there is a lot of answers out there, if there is something I need to clarify just ask me!

Answer (score 1):

You need public key encryption with key exchange.  We have a security server (A Java Program with a SOAP interface) that supports this.  There are commercial products that fulfill this requirement -- you would have to integrate them into your system.  Passwords should never be hard coded all over the place like that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest users, each user that login to SQL have its own user in the database and so it can maintain its password. You as the code that do some action beyond the session of the user can manage your password with a configurable connection string that stored in the config file and due some tool user can update it, so for example admin can always change password of his/her database and your code can work correctly. on the other hand if you have a server/client design then server can use trusted-connection and maintain its security through logged in user and never require a password to be saved in the code.

Comment: Do you men that the database connections strings with password should be in the config file with ProtectSection with DPAPI? how would you suggest to update the password and to keep it synced between the server client and server?

Answer (score 0):

So a few things.
1)  Never hard code passwords in source code, someone like me will find them.
2)  The server shouldn't be reaching into a client side database, the client should always report to the server.

Now armed with this information I would re-architect my setup to be something along these lines:

Each client sends a daily,weekly, or whatever time metric you use to get reports.  This alleviates any issues around password management.  Also by doing this the server can keep a white list of allowed clients, this prevents unauthorized or invalid clients reporting to the main server.  Now using this it doesn't matter how far behind the client is as the server surely doesn't care, and your messaging construct shouldn't change that much.  If it does you probably should force the clients to update.